# ORA-64451: Conversion of special character to escaped character failed

Tags: oracle, oracle12c

I am concatenating some texts and I get this weird error that I can't find anything about

```
UPDATE Table1 a
SET a.AllTexts = a.Text
  || a.Title
  ||
  (SELECT XMLAGG(XMLELEMENT(E,"Text",',').EXTRACT('//text()')).GetClobVal()
  FROM Table2 b
  WHERE b.El_Id = a.Id
  )
```

AllTexts is `CLOB`, all other columns are `VARCHAR2`

I get

```
Error report -
SQL Error: ORA-64451: Conversion of special character to escaped character failed.
64451. 00000 -  "Conversion of special character to escaped character failed."
*Document: NO
*Cause:    An attempt to convert a special character to an escaped character failed.
*Action:   Remove the special character that cannot be escaped.
```

**Edit:** the error is caused by some weird symbols. Problem is there is no way to know ahead which symbols will block execution

Comment: Try to narrow down the problem. Does the subquery, by itself, run OK, without the `WHERE` clause? (That is a very general principle of "troubleshooting code problems".)

Comment: It would probably also help to include the data types of the columns on your tables, and sample data (as small as possible) that generates the error.

Comment: added data types. I have a massive table, how can I catch the data that is causing the issue? thanks

Comment: I would start with the assumption that there's just one "weird" character that messes up the query (until proven otherwise). Then try to find one row that has it. If you have an id column for example, I would try to narrow it down - add a "where" clause for this id, like `where id between yyy and zzz` - and try to find as narrow a range of id's as possible that still has the same error. At each step you can cut it down in half; doing this 20 times will reduce the "possible suspects" by a factor of 1 million, so it may be manageable. Then find the exact character that causes the problem.

Answer (score 10):

I got this error code and this work for me

```
REGEXP_REPLACE(COLUMN, '[^[:print:]]', '')
```

Comment: This was helpful, but I also had to wrap the column in REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(text,CHR(47)),CHR(42)),CHR(64)),CHR(38)) to get this to work. Didn't test which of those did the trick, but for my problem needed your regexp replace and this specific character replace, just having one didn't work. Those chars are / (47), * (42), @ (64), and & (38).

Comment: That does what? It replaces every non printable char by nothing? What does :print: mean?

Comment: @DennyWeinberg https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B12037_01/server.101/b10759/ap_posix001.htm

Comment: Used this regular expression with regexp_count to identify rows that had unprintable characters. i.e. 
`select * from dual where regexp_count(dummy, '[^[:print:]]') > 0;`